# Validar formulario con Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, veevalidate

Hola mi intención es *hacer una validación con vue antes que el usuario envie el formulario*. Para **mejorar la experiencia del usuarios conforme llena el formulario** le pinte las clases de error de bootstrap.
Pero al final cuando se mande el formulario se haga de forma normal vía post, donde entraría Laravel para hacer su validación del lado del servidor.

Antes usaba jquery y jqueryValidate.

Ahora siguiendo la misma lógica uso **Vue y Vee-Validate, y todo bien ya me valida el formulario, el problema es cuando intento mandar el formulario.**

***Espero alguien me pueda orientar al respecto.***

```js
<script>
//import Vue from 'vue' //ya lo importa laravel al igual de axios
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
//Lo que nos hace la acción de pintarnos las clases de bootstrap
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  classes: true,
  classNames: {
    valid: "is-valid",
    invalid: "is-invalid"
  }
});
export default {
    data () {
       return {
         name: '',
         apellidos: '',
         email: '',
         password: '',     
         telefono: ''
       } 
    },
    methods: {
    //El metodos que manda todo a Laravel via post 
        submitForm(){
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/register',
                data: {
                    name: this.name,
                    apellidos: this.apellidos,
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password,
                    telefono: this.telefono
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- <template>  -->
<div class="container">
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md right">Nombre</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" :class="{'is-valid': true, 'is-valid': errors.has('name') }" name="name" v-validate="'required'" v-model="name" required autofocus>
                
        </div>  
    </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="apellidos" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Apellidos <span class="req" title="Requerido"><small>*</small></span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="apellidos" name="apellidos" type="text" class="form-control" :class="{'is-valid': true, 'is-valid': errors.has('apellidos') }" v-validate="'required'" v-model="apellidos" required >
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Correo electrónico <span class="req" title="Requerido"><small>*</small></span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" :class="{'is-valid': true, 'is-valid': errors.has('email') }"  v-validate="'required'" v-model="email" required>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Password <span class="req" title="Requerido"><small>*</small></span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" :class="{'is-valid': true, 'is-valid': errors.has('password') }" v-validate="'required'" v-model="password" required>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                                                <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="telefono" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">telefono <span class="req" title="Requerido"><small>*</small></span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="telefono" type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" :class="{'is-valid': true, 'is-valid': errors.has('telefono') }" v-validate="'required'" v-model="telefono" required>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row mb-5">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                                    Registrarme
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
</form>
</div>
<!-- </template> termina componente -->
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Siempre que recibas un error por favor agregalo

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿qué es lo que no funciona al enviar el formulario?

Answer (score 0):

Para validar los campos puedes utilizar `v-validate=""`, esto comprobará la primera regla y en caso de que falle no validará las siguientes. Si quieres validar todas las reglas independientemente si la anterior falla o no, puedes utilizar `v-validate.continues=""`. Para forzar que la validación no continué luego del primer fallo puedes usar `v-validate.bails=""`.

Lo anterior está sujeto a la configuración de `fastExit` que por defecto es verdadera,  `.continues` y `.bails` son modificadores de esta propiedad para forzar un comportamiento u otro.

Las reglas de validación disponibles se encuentran en la documentación y los puedes revisar en [este enlace](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/rules.html).

Para utilizar multiples reglas de validación, debes separarlas con un `|`, por ejemplo: `required|email`.

Te dejo un ejemplo extraído de la documentación.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="email" v-validate.continues="'required|email'" name="field" type="text">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="error in errors.collect('field')">{{ error }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    email: ''
  })
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

asi lo hago de la siguiente manera en el archivo de vue implemente la siguiente estructura

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">name<span class="tx-danger">*</span> </label>
        <input type="text" v-model="input_name" placeholder="name" class="form-control" :class="{'is-invalid': this.validacion.name, 'is-valid': !this.validacion.name && is_enviar}" />
        <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block" v-for="data in validacion.name" v-bind:key="data.name">
            <b>{{ data }}</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {
            //   Select2
        },
        data() {
            return {
                validacion: [],
                editar_dato: false,
                is_enviar:false,
                input_name:''
        },



      },
        methods: {
            anadir_registro() {
                this.validacion = "";
                this.editar_dato = false;
        },
            formulario(is_volve = 0) {
            this.is_enviar = true;

            const data = {
          id: this.input_id,
                telefono: this.input_telefono,
                password: this.input_password,
                email: this.input_apellidos,
                name: this.input_name,
                    };

            if (this.editar_dato == true) {
                axios.put(`${this.$url}/Api/Concreto/${this.input_id}`, data).then(
                    response => {
                        if (response.data.errors) {
                            //this.$toastr.warning("Verifique los datos", "Verifique los datos");
                            this.validacion = response.data.errors;
                        }
                        if (response.data.id) {
                            this.validacion = "";
                            //this.$toastr.success("operación exitosa", "Datos modificados");
                            //this.consulta(this.page);
                        }
                    },
                    err => {
                        //this.$toastr.warning(err, "Error en el servidor");
                        //this.$toastr.warning(err.message, "Error en el servidor");
                    }
                );
            } else {
                axios.post(`${this.$url}/Api/Concreto`, data).then(
                    response => {
                        if (response.data.errors) {
                            //this.$toastr.warning("Verifique los datos", "Verifique los datos");
                            this.validacion = response.data.errors;
                        }
                        if (response.data.id) {
                            this.validacion = "";
                            //this.$toastr.success("operación exitosa", "Datos modificados");

                            this.input_Concreto_id = response.data.id;

                        }
                    },
                    err => {
                        //this.$toastr.warning(err, "Error en el servidor");
                        //this.$toastr.warning(err.message, "Error en el servidor");
                    }
                );
            }}
        },
</script>
```

y en el archivo de laravel utilizo la siguiente estructura

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;


class ConcretoController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //$this->middleware('auth');
  }

  protected $rules =
  [
    'name' => 'required|min:1|max:255',
    'apellidos' => 'required|min:1|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
    'telefono' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
  ];

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
    } else {

     $data = new RegistroModel();
     $data->name = $request->name;
     $data->apellidos = $request->apellidos;
     $data->email = $request->email;
     $data->password = $request->password;
     $data->telefono = $request->telefono;
     $data->save();

  return response()->json($data);


    }
  }
}
```